# Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on multivariate column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 2 levels of columns which looks like this:
[image]

I am using a loop to construct charts for each country

```
import requests                 
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import read_html
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize   
import urllib2, json 
import html5lib
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

for country in WHOData.columns: # Iterate over countries
    country_df = WHOData[[country]].unstack().fillna(0) #; Unstack deaths and rates
    cases = country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Cases']
    rate = country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Rate']
    x = np.array(rate)
    y = np.array(cases)
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    results = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(x)).fit()
    plt.plot(x, results.fittedvalues)
    color = 'red'
    plt.ylabel('Measles Cases', color=color)
    color = 'blue'
    plt.xlabel('Vaccination Rate', color=color)
    plt.title(country)
    plt.show()
```

I want to remove any rows that have a 0 in either the Cases or the Rate

I tried this piece of code (with a print df rather than plotting a chart to show me what was happenning)

```
for country in WHOData.columns: # Iterate over countries
    country_df = WHOData[[country]].unstack(); # Unstack deaths and rates
    country_df = country_df.drop((country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Rate']==0)|(country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Cases']==0))
    print country_df
    break
```

And I got this error:

```
ValueError: labels [(u'Afghanistan', 'Cases') (u'Afghanistan', 'Rate')] not contained in axis
```

Which actually makes me feel like I'm close - but also has me stumped

Any help gratefully appreciated

here is the code to create this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({(u'Afghanistan', 'Cases'): {1980: 32455.0,
  1981: 31107.0,
  1982: 20320.0,
  1983: 18808.0,
  1984: 16199.0,
  1985: 14457.0},
 (u'Afghanistan', 'Pop'): {1980: 13211000.0,
  1981: 12894800.0,
  1982: 12578600.0,
  1983: 12262400.0,
  1984: 11946200.0,
  1985: 11630000.0},
 (u'Afghanistan', 'Rate'): {1980: 11.0,
  1981: 0.0,
  1982: 8.0,
  1983: 9.0,
  1984: 14.0,
  1985: 14.0},
 (u'Albania', 'Cases'): {1980: 0.0,
  1981: 0.0,
  1982: 3.0,
  1983: 17.0,
  1984: 0.0,
  1985: 0.0},
 (u'Albania', 'Pop'): {1980: 2681000.0,
  1981: 2738200.0,
  1982: 2795400.0,
  1983: 2852600.0,
  1984: 2909800.0,
  1985: 2967000.0},
 (u'Albania', 'Rate'): {1980: 90.0,
  1981: 90.0,
  1982: 93.0,
  1983: 96.0,
  1984: 96.0,
  1985: 96.0},
 (u'Algeria', 'Cases'): {1980: 15527.0,
  1981: 20849.0,
  1982: 29584.0,
  1983: 22126.0,
  1984: 22553.0,
  1985: 20114.0},
 (u'Algeria', 'Pop'): {1980: 19338000.0,
  1981: 19983600.0,
  1982: 20629200.0,
  1983: 21274800.0,
  1984: 21920400.0,
  1985: 22566000.0},
 (u'Algeria', 'Rate'): {1980: 0.0,
  1981: 0.0,
  1982: 0.0,
  1983: 0.0,
  1984: 0.0,
  1985: 68.0},
 (u'Andorra', 'Cases'): {1980: 0.0,
  1981: 0.0,
  1982: 0.0,
  1983: 0.0,
  1984: 0.0,
  1985: 0.0},
 (u'Andorra', 'Pop'): {1980: 36000.0,
  1981: 37800.0,
  1982: 39600.0,
  1983: 41400.0,
  1984: 43200.0,
  1985: 45000.0},
 (u'Andorra', 'Rate'): {1980: 0.0,
  1981: 0.0,
  1982: 0.0,
  1983: 0.0,
  1984: 0.0,
  1985: 0.0},
 (u'Angola', 'Cases'): {1980: 29656.0,
  1981: 19714.0,
  1982: 30067.0,
  1983: 22589.0,
  1984: 22685.0,
  1985: 22822.0},
 (u'Angola', 'Pop'): {1980: 8212000.0,
  1981: 8518600.0,
  1982: 8825200.0,
  1983: 9131800.0,
  1984: 9438400.0,
  1985: 9745000.0},
 (u'Angola', 'Rate'): {1980: 0.0,
  1981: 0.0,
  1982: 0.0,
  1983: 26.0,
  1984: 35.0,
  1985: 44.0}})
```

## EDIT:

here is the code that I ACTUALLY ran - it was for a much larger dataframe - approx 200 countries:

```
df=WHOData.unstack().fillna(0)
for country in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    country_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c[0] == country]]
    for c in [c for c in country_df.columns if c[1] in ['Cases', 'Rate']]:
        country_df = country_df[country_df[c] > 0]

    cases = country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Cases']
    rate = country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Rate']

    x = np.array(rate)
    y = np.array(cases)

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    results = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(x)).fit()
    plt.plot(x, results.fittedvalues)
    color = 'red'
    plt.ylabel('Measles Cases', color=color)
    color = 'blue'
    plt.xlabel('Vaccination Rate', color=color)
    plt.title(country)
    plt.show()
```

And this is a sample of how the charts looked:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over countries. For each country, iterate over the columns as tuples, and, for those whose second value is `Cases` or `Rate`, omit the relevant rows:

```
for country in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    country_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c[0] == country]]
    for c in [c for c in country_df.columns if c[1] in ['Cases', 'Rate']]:
        country_df = country_df[country_df[c] > 0]
    print(country_df)
```

This gives the following output:

```
     Afghanistan                  
           Cases         Pop  Rate
1980     32455.0  13211000.0  11.0
1982     20320.0  12578600.0   8.0
1983     18808.0  12262400.0   9.0
1984     16199.0  11946200.0  14.0
1985     14457.0  11630000.0  14.0
     Albania                 
       Cases        Pop  Rate
1982     3.0  2795400.0  93.0
1983    17.0  2852600.0  96.0
      Algeria                  
        Cases         Pop  Rate
1985  20114.0  22566000.0  68.0
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Andorra, Cases), (Andorra, Pop), (Andorra, Rate)]
Index: []
       Angola                 
        Cases        Pop  Rate
1983  22589.0  9131800.0  26.0
1984  22685.0  9438400.0  35.0
1985  22822.0  9745000.0  44.0
```

Comment: Thank you Ami - I did try this and got a completely empty dataframe as a result.  I edited into the question above what I did...

Comment: @kiltannen I added a printout of the output. Looking at your edit, I think you removed my `print` and added a `break` for some reason, so it only iterated over a single country.

Comment: OK - SO I messed up by using the WHOData without properly preparing it.  Once I ran the unstack on it correctly it worked PERFECTLY!.   THANK YOU VERY MUCH Ami!

Comment: I ran my plots on it - and they look a lot more intelligable with the "0" values dropped out.  They now show a clear relationship between the 2 datasets for each country - where before the "0"s were clouding the chart of the relationship

Comment: @kiltannen Very nice example of data cleanup.

Comment: I think I MAY be starting to get a handle on some of the more simple approaches to Data Wrangling.  I have a long way to go still - but some of the answers I see here are starting to make sense for me instead of just being complete arcane mysteries.